# Different type in lamda with reference in capture list

Tags: c++

It is fine to compile these code in c11

```
double(*p1)(double) = [](double a) { return sqrt(a); };

double(*p2)(double) = [&](double a) { return sqrt(a); };
```

But there is the following error in compilation in c17

> double(*p2)(double) = [&](double a) { return sqrt(a); };
>
> cannot convert test_pointer_to_function::test_method()::<lambda(double)> to double (*)(double) in initialization    double(*p2)(double) = [&](double a) { return sqrt(a); };

What is the correct type for this lamda function?

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: It would be better to use `std::function<double(double)> p2 = ...` or simply use `auto p2 = ...`

Comment: Firstly, it is C++11 and C++17, not "c11" and "c17". Secondly, what made you to conclude that "it is fine" in C++11? The second initialization is illegal in C++11 just at it is illegal in C++17.

Comment: Your error message looks strange. Are you sure you quoted the right error message? I don't see any `test_pointer_to_function` or `test_method` in the code you posted. Yet, they are mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "correct" function pointer type for lambda expression with non-empty *lambda-capture*. Such closure objects are not convertible to ordinary function pointers.

If you want to be able to convert closure object to ordinary function pointer type, make sure you have nothing in the `[]` part of lambda expression. This applies to C++11 and later, including C++17.

Answer (score 1):

Each lambda has its own unique type. Normally, if you need to assign a lambda to a variable, you use `auto` for its type. If you need a known type (e.g. you are going to store lambdas in a container), you can use `std::function` with the same signature as your lambda. In your example, this will be

```
std::function<double(double)> p2 = [&](double a) { return sqrt(a); };
```

(but note that you generally lose some efficiency this way).

Only non-capturing lambdas, i.e. lambdas with empty `[]`, are convertible to a function pointer, like in your example:

```
double(*p1)(double) = [](double a) { return sqrt(a); };
```

Your C++11 compiler should not have accepted

```
double(*p2)(double) = [&](double a) { return sqrt(a); };
```